# Microsoft Graph. DriveItem Id format?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

Looks like, in Microsoft Graph and OneDrive `Id` for [drive](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/drive) and [drive item](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem) has special internal format:

- Drive `Id` is equal to unique identifier of the user.
- Drive item `Id` is `[DirevId]![ItemNo]`.

Am I right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements that are made for the identifiers are:
`driveId` = Uniquely identifies a drive
`itemId` = Uniquely identifies an item within a drive

The actual values of the identifiers are documented to be opaque blobs, and so any meaning inferred from them is not guaranteed to work long term, or across all scenarios. A prime example of this is the different values provided from the Business and Consumer services.

Comment: If I have `itemId`, How can I define `driveId` for which this item belongs? Or I should keep the pair `driveId` + `itemId` for unambiguous resource definition?

Comment: If the item is for your own drive, and you can therefore access it using `/drive`, you technically don't need to store the `driveId` because it's implied by the authentication. Generally speaking, however, you should keep both.

Comment: This answer is definatly correct; the format for a DriveItemId has changed!

Comment: Which documentation does say the ids are opaque blobs?